# ¿Como ocultar el scrollbar?

Tags: html, css

Quisiera quitar mi `scrollbar` de la vista del usuario, como actualmente no se a que se debe que cuando se marca un error un recuadro aprece arriba de mi formulario y por ende desplaza unos pixeles a mi formulario y ese en este movimiento en donde el `scrollbar` horizontal en la parte inferior de mi formulario aparece, me gustaría saber si hay una forma de ocultar el `scrollbar`, para que este ya no se vea.

Imagen de ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Lo puedes hacer con CSS con `overflow: hidden;`

Answer (score 16):

Es cierto que con **`overflow: hidden;`** se puede resolver, pero creo que no es el método correcto, ya que de este modo estás inhabilitando el **scroll** dentro de ese **`<div>`** pero en tu caso da igual ya que no es necesario hacer **scroll**, pero... ¿que ocurriría si añades más contenido y **necesitas hacer scroll** y al **mismo tiempo ocultar la barra de desplazamiento**?

Con el siguiente estilo CSS lo resuelves:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}
```

Esto ocultará todas las barras de desplazamiento, pero luego si quieres puedes aplicar ese estilo a tan solo un elemento con una id o una clase.

Espero que te sirva de ayuda

Answer (score 10):

Puedes usar el atributo `overflow: hidden;` para ocultar la barra de desplazamiento *horizontal* y *vertical*.

Si deseas solamente ocultar tu barra de desplazamiento *horizontal*, puedes utilizar el atributo `overflow-x: hidden;` o para el caso *vertical* `overflow-y: hidden;`.

Comment: Debería ser la respuesta correcta, por utilizar overflow-x y overflow-y

Answer (score 2):

Aunque la pregunta es algo antigua, creo que debo responder porque las respuestas que se han dado son en principio un parche. Tenemos dos cuestiones entonces:

1. Solventar la razón por la que se genera ese scroll. Por mi experiencia diría que lar razón es que esa alerta tiene una regla CSS *width* igual al padre que también tiene un *padding*. La solución sería utilizar width: 100%; en el alert pues de otra forma al sumar los *paddings* del padre, el espacio disponible es menor y provoca el overflow. Os dejo una simulación.

```css
section {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 240px;
  height: 120px;
  padding: 24px;
  background: lightgrey;
  border-radius: 12px;
 }
 .alert {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 240px;
  padding: 12px;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 6px;
 }
 .alert2 {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 6px;
 }
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="alert">Alert box con scroll</div>
</section>
<section>
  <div class="alert2">Alert box sin scroll</div>
</section>
```

2. Si el alert ya tuviese un width 100% entonces probablemente la razón es que tiene margins, por lo que entonces la solución sería una de dos: 1) eliminar los margins; 2) Restarlos del width mediante `width: calc(100% - [valor del margin]*2)`
3. Para los que realmente necesiten ocultar el scroll, antes de hacerlo les recomiendo que se lean este artículo: [Ocultar el scroll con CSS](https://elcssar.com/css/hide-scroll)
   Podrán aprender las distintas formas de hacerlo y las alternativas para resolver muchos de los problemas que les han llevado a la conclusión de que deben esconderlo.

Answer (score 1):

Para quitar el scroll vertical pon este código en tu fichero *style.css*
No necesitarás JavaScript. Pruébenlo:

```
html,body{
  overflow-x: hidden;
  color:black;
  font-family:'Opens Sans',helvetica;  
  height:100%;
  width:101%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
```