# CSS - ¿Cómo hacer que el track del scrollbar no se vea?

Tags: css, scss, scrollbar

necesito hacer que el track del scrollbar sea invisible.

Por más de que le coloque el background con alpha en 0 el fondo al fin y al cabo sigue siendo blanco. lo quiero hacer como lo hice anteriormente con un proyecto, pero no recuerdo cómo lo hice.

El código que tengo en ambos proyectos es este:

```
html { --scrollbarBG: #000; --thumbBG: #360070; }

body {
overflow-x: hidden;
scrollbar-width: thin;
scrollbar-color: var(--thumbBG) var(--scrollbarBG);
margin: 0;
padding: 0; }

body ::-webkit-scrollbar {width: 7px;}
body ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {background: rgba($color: #000, $alpha: 0);}
body ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {background-color: var(--thumbBG); border: 3px solid var(--thumbBG);}
```

Adjunto imagen de cómo quedo en mi proyecto anterior: [image: Scrollbar sin track] Y así se ve en mi proyecto actual: [image: Track blanco]

En la foto 2 se ve el track, pero la configuración es la misma

Comment: Puedes ver aqui https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/56179/como-ocultar-el-scrollbar/56180

Comment: Gracias @HernánGarcia, pero el error fue mío. Estaba tratando de cambiar el scroll del body, pero en realidad el scroll que yo estaba utilizando era el de la seccion CONTAINER, solamente tenia que poner `overflow: overlay` para solucionarlo.
GRACIAS DE IGUAL MANERA!